# jQuery - after click close one div and keep others issuse

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

**Hi There,**

**HTML code**

```
<button class="view btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".collapse">View Content</button>
<div class=" collapse">
    <div class="main-content">
        <p>Hello World</p>
        <button class="close btn">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
<button type="rest" class="repeat btn col-md-12">Repeat</button>
```

**Jquery code :**

```
    $(".main-content .close").click(function () {
          $(this).parents(".collapse").removeClass("in");
     });
    $(".repeat.btn").click(function (e) {

         e.preventDefault(); // to prevent form submit
         var $self = $(this);
         $self.before($self.prev('.collapse.in').clone());

    });
```

*Steps of my idea are  :*

1 - Collapse div -- using `Bootstrap framework`

2 - Repeat this div -- after click on the repeat button

3 - User can close one div before and after repeating

Third one is my issue ... It works when i click on close button before repeat the content .....  But after repeating doesn't

Any help please

*please ask if anything doesn't clear.*

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Norhan/1tLof1ph/10/)

Comment: ooh..actually it works with me ... i don't know why it not work

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work because of https://

Comment: @Dennis the demo is working now

Comment: @MHakvoort   the demo is working now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

```
$(document).on("click", ".close", function () {
    $(this).parents(".collapse").removeClass("in");

});
$(".repeat.btn").click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault(); // to prevent form submit
    var $self = $(this);
    $self.before($self.prev('.collapse.in').clone());

});
```

It has something to do with [Event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). Good luck.

**[SEE UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1tLof1ph/9/)**

Comment: ooh..actually it works with me ... i don't know why it not work

Comment: What are you doing here? EDIT: your syntax for delegating is wrong here, you mean certainly: `$(document).on("click", ".repeat.btn", function (e) {...});`

Comment: @Dennis But your syntax is wrong :)  Here you are delegating click event for an element of type `document` at `.repeat.btn` element level, which doesn't exist. But i guess you are correct, OP needs delegation

Comment: @A.Wolff, OMG ur right! Fixed it now, including with the JSFiddle ;)

Comment: @Norhan, please check my fiddle. That's also working now correctly as you intended :)

Comment: @Dennis   .... ya it works !!  ... thanks alot :)
so the problem here was event delegation

Comment: @Norhan, yep, that's correct. Had me pulling my hair out a few times as well ;)

Comment: @Dennis ..hahah...  ya same i was before your answer :D

Comment: I found another issue in the collapsing action .....
when i close all divs and then click on the view content .... the content isn't open new one ..... and when i close 2 of 4 of the repeating divs .... it didn't collapse right ... I want to collapse right ..... as when i click on view content ...if there are divs open ..all should be collapsed ..and when i close all divs then click on the view button ...it should display new one ..and so on